Getting 422 Unprocessable Entity while sending a GET request with list of data to FastAPI backend
I have created a fastAPI based endpoint which is responsible for accepting month, card_no, schema_order as a payload parameter and perform db select query and return json data as a output.
code snippet:
@app.get("/fetch-data/")
def fetch_data(
    month: str,  # Mandate filter: execution month (yyyy/mm/dd)
    card_no: list[int],  # Optional filter: list of card numbers
    schema_order: list[str] = None,  # Input schema_order (optional)
):
try:
    # Query the database based on filters
    db = SessionLocal()
    query = db.query(CardData).filter(CardData.month == month)
    if card_no:
        query = query.filter(CardData.card_no.in_(card_no))
    data = query.all()

    # Prepare output based on schema_order (if provided)
    if schema_order:
        output = [{col: getattr(item, col) for col in schema_order} for item in data]
    else:
        output = [item.dict() for item in data]

    return output
except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error fetching data: {str(e)}")

Now i am trying to perform curl request to the above api which is giving me 422 Unprocessable Entity
curl request:
curl -X "GET" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/fetch-data/?month=2024-01-06&card_no=123456789" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
Error which i am getting after this curl request is :
422 Unprocessable Entity
error in response as {"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","card_no"],"msg":"Field required","input":null,"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/missing"}]}

I need help to curl this API currently facing issues

In addition to the link provided above, you might find this answer, this answer, as well as this answer and this answer helpful too.
